# How to get suggestions when writing python code (discord api)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot for fun and have run into some inconvenience. For example in this function

```
@client.event
    async def on_message(message):
```

When I write `message.` PyCharm (does this work in other editors?) doesn't show suggestions for available methods, properties, etc. Is it possible to set this up so that for example when I type `message.` suggestions will come up, such as `author`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you may need to set a type to your parameter.

```
import discord
@client.event
    async def on_message(message:Discord.message):
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look a lot at the documentation for most things https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Your `message` example is listed in here https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message